# Where to add output to file command to while loop

Tags: command-line

I have this command which reads in a long text file and uses the text on each line as a variable to another command. Here it is:

```
input="test_file.txt"
while IFS= read -r line; do
#This bit just concatenates some strings to use as args
first_str="my str"
second_str="my 2nd str"
third_str="my 3rd str"
str1="${first_str} ${line}"
str2="${second_str} ${line}"
str3="${third_str} ${line}"
#Then the strings are used as args to a script
$WS/DevTools/src/script.py -d Argument "${str1}" && $WS/DevTools/src/script.py -d Argument "${str2}" && $WS/DevTools/src/script.py -d Argument -x "Type=x" "${str3}" 
done < "$input"
```

This is good and does want I want, but everything is printed to standard output. Since there are thousands of tests, this output is huge.

I want to print everything to a file. This is what I tried and it didn't work. The bits that I changed were creating test_results file at the top, and and then after the command appending the output to test_results

```
: > test_results
input="test_file.txt"
while IFS= read -r line; do
#This bit just concatenates some strings to use as args
first_str="my str"
second_str="my 2nd str"
third_str="my 3rd str"
str1="${first_str} ${line}"
str2="${second_str} ${line}"
str3="${third_str} ${line}"
#Then the strings are used as args to a script
$WS/DevTools/src/script.py -d Argument "${str1}" && $WS/DevTools/src/script.py -d Argument "${str2}" && $WS/DevTools/src/script.py -d Argument -x "Type=x" "${str3}" >> test_results
done < "$input"
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sorry, but due to formatting limits of the software which runs Stack Exchange, what you wanted to appear bolded, does not.

Comment: I have removed the bolded part and included a description of which part of the command is changed instead. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Apologies, I did actually use the correct >> output redirection in the command. This got messed up because I was editing the command to anonymize my artifacts. Edited to show the correct >> output redirection which I used.

Comment: Note that you're chaining 3 commands together (with `&&`) however the `>>` redirection operator will apply only to the last one - is that what you intended?